# Auto update a weekly timer date with PHP

Tags: php

Currently I am manually updating the `$offer_end_date` I would like this date to automatically update once the time and date has been reached.

The script I'm using:

```
<?php

$offer_end_date = strtotime('2016-02-25 17:00:00');
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

?>
```

**UPDATED**

If anyone else has this question I solved it by using The Avon Guys answer + an if else statement as once the timer reached the 'this wednesday' date ot failed to reset as it was still 'this wednesday'.

```
$set_end_date = strtotime('this wednesday 17:00:00');
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
if($set_end_date >= $current_date) {
    $offer_end_date = $set_end_date;
} else {
    $offer_end_date = strtotime('next wednesday 17:00:00');
}
```

Comment: what is the question? it's not clear from your code snippet, where do you have the difficulty?

Comment: are you basically asking if your "offer" clock can be reset to the end of the following week as soon as the current week is ending? In effect making the "offer" a misleading title, as it is a permanent discount?

Comment: Currently I am manually updating the `$offer_end_date` I would like this date to automatically update once the time and date has been reached.

Comment: $offer_end_date =strtotime('this sunday');

Comment: If you are really making a fradulent offer, and the clock is just counting down to sunday and restarting, you could make it clientside in javascript.

Btw, read up on this: https://www.asa.org.uk/

Comment: @Theavonguy would you like to add your answer so  I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the offer end date auto generate to a fixed future point but a fixed future point that is always within the next x number of days, probably makes sense to use strtotime:

```
 $offer_end_date =strtotime('this sunday');
```

However, I would also add that in many jurisdictions, what you are proposing to do is illegal, and even where it is not illegal it is unethical. You are creating false scarcity. An offer with a limited duration must, by definition have a limited duration. You are potentially opening yourself up for a legal backlash. In the UK a discounted price must:

- explain the price comparison clearly and unambiguously
- make sure the price you use for the comparison is your most recent price that was available for 28 days in a row or more - if you use an earlier price you'll need to make that clear
- include details of both the previous and the new price
- make sure the basis of the price comparison is reasonable in terms of time - ideally the period during which the new price is available shouldn't be longer than the period during which the old higher price was on offer
- avoid comparisons with prices that you offered more than six months ago

[UK Government Pricing Law Guidelines](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbiIfAzZDLAhXBGA8KHdc2DoEQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gov.uk%2Fgovernment%2Fuploads%2Fsystem%2Fuploads%2Fattachment_data%2Ffile%2F31900%2F10-1312-pricing-practices-guidance-for-traders.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFfHMd8EIdCaR4ZBfqOKfN5-2b7Cg&sig2=rg5k60y43jwbF0M1rAVaOA)

Comment: Thanks, perfect. I'm also using this to set variables that change the offers, but didn't feel like I needed to explain that in my question.

Comment: Ive updated my question using your example and a little fix for the timer not updating when it's still on 'this day'.